# How can I override bootstrap 4 default font with multiple font-faces?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face

I want to know if it is possible to override bootstrap with a font-face family. I have font-faces:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont Normal';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local(customFont-Normal),
    url(<filepath>) format(<file_type>);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont Bold';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local(customFont-Bold),
    url(<filepath>) format(<file_type>);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont Thin';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local(customFont-Thin),
    url(<filepath>) format(<file_type>);
}
```

From what I understood with font-face, having multiple font-faces at different weights allows me to automatically apply these fonts to my HTML whenever I specify a weight on the element and it would match to the closest weight. But I am currently using bootstrap v4 and it has its own default font. So I added this to my scss to override it:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'customFont Normal', 'customFont Bold', 'customFont Thin', -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !default;
$font-family-monospace:  Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace !default;
$font-family-base:       $font-family-sans-serif !default;
```

But this only applies the first font-face to my website, and changing the weights on the elements did not change the font. Is there a way to combine all of these together to override bootstrap font while keeping the functionality of font-face? I have read that this may work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont'
  src: url(<normal>) format() font-weight: 400,
    url(<bold>) format() font-weight: 700,
    url(<thin>) format() font-weight: 200,
}
```

And I tried adding that in front of `$font-family-sans-serif` but it had ignored and did not apply any font. Is my approach wrong or is there a better method on doing this?

Edit:
I decided to change the names of all the font-family to the same name but kept everything else the same. My second method was giving errors so I went with this method and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your fonts the same name, now if you change the font-weights, it should switch correctly.

EDIT: Just realized that you've already mentioned this in your question

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'customFont'
  src: url(<normal>) format() font-weight: 400,
    url(<bold>) format() font-weight: 700,
    url(<thin>) format() font-weight: 200,
}
```

make sure you override it with the correct font-family:

```
$font-family-sans-serif: 'customFont', -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !default;
$font-family-monospace:  Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace !default;
$font-family-base:       $font-family-sans-serif !default;
```

Comment: I tried the second method but I am getting issues with the font-weight syntax. Is the format I defined correct?